# 2000 Chevy Silverado 5.3L turns over but won't start, no spark

Tags: starting, chevrolet

A few weeks ago I noticed that the wire going to the starter from the solinoid was broken off at the connection, so I resoldered it, and it ran for a few weeks until this happened:

I went out to start my truck and it just clicked when i tried to turn it over. I pushed it into the garage and replaced the starter with a used one. Went to start truck and all it did was turn the starter but wouldn't fire up and run. I tested the sensors and it read to replace crankshaft position sensor along with the MAP sensor. Still doesn't want to run. I replaced the spark plugs, but left one out to check for spark against the metal frame didn't see any spark.  Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

HAve you tested the battery? If you have a bad battery, it could cause the starter to click like that.